# Intuition about the application of padding masks and look-ahead masks in Transformer's encoder/decoder

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, transformers

From the [Tensorflow tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/text/tutorials/transformer), the shape of the padding mask is `(batch_size, 1, 1, seq_len)` and look-ahead mask is `(batch_size, 1, seq_len, seq_len)` which fed into `scaled_dot_product` function along with $q,v,k$.

For input $X$ with shape `(batch_size, seq_len)` of integer tokens that are then converted to an embedding, the resulting Tensor, let's call $X'$ has shape `(batch_size, seq_len, d_model)`. In the call method of `MultiHeadAttention` class of the tutorial we have:

```
def call(self, v, k, q, mask):
   batch_size = tf.shape(q)[0]

   q = self.wq(q)  # (batch_size, seq_len, d_model)
   k = self.wk(k)  # (batch_size, seq_len, d_model)
   v = self.wv(v)  # (batch_size, seq_len, d_model)

   q = self.split_heads(q, batch_size)  # (batch_size, num_heads, seq_len_q, depth)
   k = self.split_heads(k, batch_size)  # (batch_size, num_heads, seq_len_k, depth)
   v = self.split_heads(v, batch_size)  # (batch_size, num_heads, seq_len_v, depth)

   scaled_attention, attention_weights = scaled_dot_product_attention(
    q, k, v, mask)

   ....
```

If $q=v=k=X'$ are input into the above `call`, then input into `scaled_dot_product` in the last line would be tensors of shape   `(batch_size, num_head, seq_len, depth )`.Then, in the first line of `scaled_dot_product`:

```
matmul_qk = tf.matmul(q, k, transpose_b=True)
```

would result in `matmul_qk` having a shape of `(batch_size, num_head, seq_len, seq_len )`, and this Tensor then has the masked applied via:

```
if mask is not None:
   scaled_attention_logits += (mask * -1e9)
```

I understand that the shape of the masks (via broadcasting) matches that of the shape of `matmul_qk` above, but after all of the transformations of the original $X$, I'm having a hard time visualizing how the padding and look-ahead masks are doing what they are intended to do. For instance, how is the `(batch_size, 1, 1, seq_len)` padding mask created based on padded `0`s in the original input $X$ of integers tokens end up masking padded values in `matmul_qk`?

Answer (score 2):

The mask is typically a square matrix with a upper-right triangle of ones (or True in the pytorch implementation), and the rest is filled with zeros.

```
0 1 1 1
0 0 1 1
0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0
```

The ones will mask/put to zero the attention coefficients on those positions (read below). The shape of this matrix, a upper-right triangle, allows the transformer to avoid a look ahead bias (google this term together with time series), that is the current inputs can attend/pay attention to themselves and to past input data, but not to future input data. Otherwise the algorithm would be cheating.

How does the mask work? Look at the last piece of code that you show in your question. That `-1e9` is a very low number simulating minus infinity. Therefore, `mask * -1e9` becomes a matrix with zeroes and minus infinity on what you want to mask. `scaled_attention_logits` becomes a matrix with a upper-right triangle of very low numbers. Thereafter the architecture includes softmax, which puts to zero all minus infinity, effectively masking the upper-right triangle.

A doubt that I am having and that I am going to ask on a different post is how come the residual connection on the attention block does not cause any look ahead bias.

Comment: Have you got any answer to your doubt?

Comment: why would there be look ahead bias?  the residual layer "looks ahead" in the layers dimension while the mask works in the position dimension.   the residual layer cannot by itself "look ahead" in the position dimension